# Instaling Solr PHP JAVA_HOME error

Tags: java, php, solr

I'm trying to install Solr PHP via the command line on my server

I'm running the installation with

```
root@vps25581 [/opt]# ./install_solr_service.sh  solr-6.4.1.tgz
```

but I keep getting this error:

> The currently defined JAVA_HOME (/usr/local/jdk) refers
>       to a location where Java could not be found.  Aborting.
>       Either fix the JAVA_HOME variable or remove it from the
>       environment so that the system PATH will be searched.

but when I `echo $JAVA_HOME` i get: `/usr/bin/java`

Also when I check the directory `/usr/bin/java` I can't find any .jdk files or any other files there

How can I find the right location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/java
```

is most likely a symbolic link.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/java
```

will show you what it is currently pointing to.

If it needs updated use this command:

```
ln -sfn <locationOfJDK> /usr/bin/java
```

to update the symbolic link and attempt to re-install.

Comment: i got:lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Feb 10 12:09 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java*
how do i fined the reale location of JDK?

Comment: I'm not sure where the JDK would be located on your server. It may be best to install a fresh JDK and update the symlink to point to it.